# Command line utility in Unix to output hashes

Tags: security, unix, command-line, hash

Did some searching online and couldn't find anything. Ideally it would be cool to have a binary on my machine like:

`hashme -n sha256 "some string"`

Would be nice to have support for:

- sha-1
- sha-256
- md5
- bcrypt with number of iterations

etc, etc.

Does such a tool exist? It would be relatively easy (?) to implement myself given that other binaries exist for other hashes, like `sha1sum` for example - but just wondered if it was out there and I couldn't find it.

Comment: I created my own using Perl.  That doesn't help you much; it is absolutely no proof that it hasn't been done sensibly and released by someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [sha256sum](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sha256sum) for example, or better still, [shasum](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shasum) e.g.

```
$ shasum -a 256 < myfile.txt
```

[md5sum](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl_md5sum.htm) performs the same using the MD5 algorithm.

I'm sure it would be trivial to wrap all of these with one shell script (e.g. Perl) that uses an option to select the binary to pipe into. Note that those suggested above all work in a broadly similar fashion so a wrapper script would be relatively easy.

Answer (score 3):

> Ideally it would be cool to have a binary on my machine like:
>
> hashme -n sha256 "some string"

Your wish has been granted. (Maybe...) Look at the [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html) command. It's available on most Unix systems and can calculate a wide variety of checksums and encoding of files.